# How to get the current module name in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So, I could accomplish this by using `'topLevelSomething` and removing the last token after ., or I could use `moduleName 'something` but that returns a Maybe...

Is there a more straightforward way to get the module name of the current context?

So, given the code:

```
module My.Module.Blah where
test = magicHere
```

What goes in that magicHere spot such that test = "My.Module.Blah" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great answers. We ended up doing it this way as it seemed a little cleaner.

```
moduleOf 'someTopLevelThingInModule

moduleOf :: Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Name -> String
moduleOf = dropLastToken . show
dropLastToken :: String -> String
dropLastToken = reverse . tail . dropWhile (/= '.') . reverse
```

Answer (score 14):

I thought this was a nice question, so I figured out the answer using Template Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module A.B.C where

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

e :: String
e = $(fmap loc_module qLocation >>= \mod ->  return (LitE (StringL mod) ))

main = print e
```

Comment: Note that I think this bit of Template Haskell only works at compile time, using runQ at runtime will not work.

Answer (score 10):

There's a rather roundabout way to get the current module name using Typeable.

```
module My.Module.Blah where
import Data.Typeable

data T = T deriving Typeable
test = init $ init $ show $ typeOf T
```